# What do brk and sbrk stand for?

Tags: c, unix, sbrk, brk

While I know what the Unix system call `brk` and function `sbrk` do, I have no idea what they stand for. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Just do a 'man brk' and the meaning is clear from the description.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It comes from "break value".

I quote:
"The change is made  by resetting  the  process's  break  value  and  allocating the appropriate amount of space. The break value is the  address of  the  first  location beyond the end of the data segment."

(source: http://www.s-gms.ms.edus.si/cgi-bin/man-cgi?brk+2)

Comment: come on ! "brk" is break indeed, now you still miss the "s". You're doing a cliffhanger here.

Comment: If I had to wager a guess it would be that the "s" in `sbrk` stands for "space", because its argument adds (or removes) `<increment>` *space* to the heap.

Comment: @Iguananaut: S could also be Successor function, which is the math version of increment.

Comment: Or the 's' could stand for "shift" as in "shift the break" with a negative amount to decrement or shift with a positive amount to increment.

Answer (score 3):

Just read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk):

brk() and sbrk() change the location of the **program break**, which defines the end of the process's data segment (i.e., the program break is the first location after the end of the uninitialized data segment). Increasing the program break has the effect of allocating memory to the process; decreasing the break deallocates memory.

brk() sets the end of the data segment to the value specified by addr, when that value is reasonable, the system has enough memory, and the process does not exceed its maximum data size (see setrlimit(2)).

sbrk() increments the program's **data space** by increment bytes. Calling sbrk() with an increment of 0 can be used to find the current location of the program break.